# Apollo client specific updatequery for all items?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have two models with the following relation:

**Groups** has many
**Links**

So basically my initial query is getAllGroups, which fetches all groups and its links.
I have a mutation which simply creates a link, what is the most efficient way to update my UI?

Currently I have:

```
export const withCreateLink = graphql(createLink, {
props({ownProps, mutate}) {
    return {
        createLink(url, description, group) {
            return mutate({
                variables: {
                    url,
                    description,
                    group
                },
                updateQueries: {
                    getAllGroups: (prev, {mutationResult}) => {
                        const newLink = mutationResult.data.createLink;
                        return update(prev, {
                            allGroups: {
                                links: {
                                    $push: [newLink]
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
});
```

Basically I only want to fetch the group which has the link added to it, but I need to specify which group that is. How do I go about this?

Comment: So you want to add a link to a specific group? Because now you add the new link to all groups

Comment: Yeah, but I guess I already figured it out. I can receive the group index from my props, and then use that index in my query: allGroups: { [groupIndex]: { links: {...} }}. Right? I will add that as answer. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: yes looks like the correct way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already figured it out, while creating other mutations this way i've found some different approaches to tackle this:

**Option 1:** 
If you have access to the index of the current model that's in your cache, you can pass it as a prop and then use it inside of your query to target the one that it has been added to:

```
                updateQueries: {
                getAllGroups: (prev, {mutationResult}) => {
                    const newLink = mutationResult.data.createLink;
                    return update(prev, {
                        allGroups: {
                            [groupIndex]:
                              links: {
                                 $push: [newLink]
                              }
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
```

**Option 2:** Using update instead of updateQueries, so you can read the result of the root query, map over it and then append the newly inserted data. After this you can write it to the cache.

```
                    update: (proxy, mutationResult) => {
                    const query = getAllGroups;
                    const data = proxy.readQuery({query});

                    data.allGroups.map((groupData) => {
                        if(groupData.id == group)
                            groupData.links.push(mutationResult.data.createLink);
                    });

                    proxy.writeQuery({
                        query,
                        data
                    })
                }
```